# Camera preview size is not full screen

Tags: android, android-camera, screen-size

I have a problem with my camera in my app and that it is not full screen when I run the app. I have a screen shot of the camera that I will post later. The main activity class get its screen size from the camera preview class so I will not be posting its code even though I have the layout for it (which hosts the camera on it).

CameraPreview.java

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
    private OnFocusChangeListener onFocusListener;
    private boolean needToTakePic = false;
    private boolean isLightOn = false;
    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mCamera = camera;
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();


        this.mCamera = camera;
        this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


        // supported preview sizes
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        for(Camera.Size str: mSupportedPreviewSizes)
            Log.e(TAG, str.width + "/" + str.height);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.getParameters().setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // left blank for now
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.removeCallback(this);
        mCamera.release();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged => w=" + w + ", h=" + h);
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // intentionally left blank for a test
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }

        float ratio;
        if(mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
        else
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;

        // One of these methods should be used, second method squishes preview slightly
        setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
//        setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * ratio), height);
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }

    private Camera.AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
            if (arg0) {
                mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
            }
        }
    };


    public void doTouchFocus(final Rect tfocusRect) {
        try {
            List<Camera.Area> focusList = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
            Camera.Area focusArea = new Camera.Area(tfocusRect, 1000);
            focusList.add(focusArea);

            Camera.Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
            param.setFocusAreas(focusList);
            param.setMeteringAreas(focusList);
            mCamera.setParameters(param);

            mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (isNeedToTakePic()) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            Rect touchRect = new Rect(
                    (int) (x - 100),
                    (int) (y - 100),
                    (int) (x + 100),
                    (int) (y + 100));


            final Rect targetFocusRect = new Rect(
                    touchRect.left * 2000 / this.getWidth() - 1000,
                    touchRect.top * 2000 / this.getHeight() - 1000,
                    touchRect.right * 2000 / this.getWidth() - 1000,
                    touchRect.bottom * 2000 / this.getHeight() - 1000);

            doTouchFocus(targetFocusRect);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean isNeedToTakePic() {
        return needToTakePic;
    }

    public void setNeedToTakePic(boolean needToTakePic) {
        this.needToTakePic = needToTakePic;
    }
    public void turnOnFlashLight() {
        if (isLightOn == true) {
            Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
            p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            mCamera.setParameters(p);
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            isLightOn = false;


        }else{


            isLightOn = true;

        }
    }

    private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){

                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000"
 >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id = "@+id/bearPaw"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="48dp" />




    <Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id = "@+id/flah_off"
    android:background="@mipmap/flah_off"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that this Camera plugin is being used anymore, and I do not believe that I was able to resolve the issue, but I am no longer working on this project. I hope that this code that I provided helps others fix their issues with the Camera plugin.